# Voice Recorder in iOS Application

Tags: ios5

i am developing a iOS application with Audio recorder. I am using AVAudioRecorder as well as AVAudioPlayer. I have use this two in the Same view.My application also need to play and record audio in background mode. When i tried here all are working fine.I tried many different things, but my application continuously getting reject.Please give me the Solution.
 How can i set the AVAudioSession for this condition.

Comment: Your app gets rejected from the app store?  Does Apple provide a reason for the rejection?

Comment: Yes sir. Apple said that i had enabled the background mode for audio play. but there wae no audio file played in background.

Comment: But In my device, it is working fine.